# Please help save me an extra image write in ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

In Windows ImageMagick, I have to rotate an image before I can place it on the page:

> convert .\source1.png -alpha set -background none -rotate 15 rotate.png

I then place it on the page:

```
composite -compose over .\rotate.png -geometry +103+160 bg.png output.png
```

I'm trying to figure out how to not do the "rotate.png" write to disk, but just store it in memory until the composite step. I've tried:

```
composite -compose over ( .\source1.png -alpha set -background none -rotate 15 ) .\source1shadow.png .\bg.png  output.png
```

Is there a way to make this work? Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use the pipe character to write the image to RAM:

convert .\source1.png -alpha set -background none -rotate 15 png:- | composite -compose over -geometry +103+160 bg.png output.png

Docs:
http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php